# Why am i getting error when using an ajax call to retrieve my teams - using graph api https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams

Tags: microsoft-teams, graph-api

I'm trying to get my teams(The teams i have joined) via an ajax call.

Sample below

```
function getmyTeams() {  
    $.ajax({  
        method: 'GET',  
        url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com",  
        //url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams",
        headers: {  
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,  
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'  
        },  
    }).success(function(response) {  
        console.log(response); 

    }).error(function(error) {});  
}
```

But i'm getting error

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams 404 (Not Found)
```

I can confirm the access token works with no issues as i can retrieve data when i use this api below

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com
```

to get current users details
I have also added this api permissions for graph
[image]

**Some update**
when i use postman now i get error below

```
Failed to execute MsGraph backend request GetUserGroupsS2SRequest
Request Url: https://graph.microsoft.com/edu/users/guid/memberOf/$/microsoft.graph.group?$filter=groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified')&$top=999, Request Method: GET, Response Status Code: NotFound, Response Headers: request-id: 5ebe3625-64e5-4dac-9649-3665fadf716b\r\nclient-request-id: 5ebe3625-64e5-4dac-9649-3665fadf716b\r\nStrict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000\r\nDate: Tue, 19 May 2020 08:24:59 GMT\r\n, Reason Phrase: Not Found"
```

Any ideas what i'm missing?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Yes..it was authentication issue